# ¿hay manera de clasificar los echo obtenidos?

Tags: javascript, php

```js
if (// INSTRUCCIONES) {

echo "Primer mensaje";
echo "Segundo mensaje";
echo "Tercer mensaje";

}


// PARA POSTERIORMENTE DESPUÉS DE HABER OBTENIDO LOS ECHO POR MEDIO DE HTTTP REQUEST HACER ESTO EN JAVASCRIPT

var a;
var b;
var c;

a = //echo mensaje 1
b = //echo mensaje 2
c = //echo mensaje 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ello declaras las variables y despues los muestras con echo

```
if (/* INSTRUCCIONES */) {

$a = "Primer mensaje";
$b = "Segundo mensaje";
$c = "Tercer mensaje";

//si quieres hacer echo en esta area
echo $a;
echo $b;
echo $c;
}


//y despues en esta area
echo $a;
echo $b;
echo $c;
```